# Error with Azure hosted service " An error occurred while sending the request"

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

We have started getting an error with one of our *ASP.NET Web API* services that is hosted with *Azure App Service*. The service allows for images to be posted (as serialised byte arrays) to our backend. This service has been running without any problems for well over a year, but has suddenly started throwing up the following error.

> PostInspectionImagesTests threw exception: 
>   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending
>   the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection
>   was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. --->
>   System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection
>   was forcibly closed by the remote host

Here is the code that posts the request.

```
private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostData(string url, HttpContent content, string token)
{
    RoutingTasksPostDeploymentTests.Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(RoutingTasksPostDeploymentTests.Subscriber, token);
    return await RoutingTasksPostDeploymentTests.Client.PostAsync(new Uri(url), content);
}
```

We use a static instance of the *HttpClient* class as it's way more efficient.

Here is the code that I use to create test images.

```
private static byte[] GetImage(int imageSize)
{
    var randBytes = new byte[imageSize];
    System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider rand = 
        new System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    rand.GetBytes(randBytes);
    return randBytes;
}
```

I can post images <1MB in size but when I get to >1MB I get the error. This service has been working for well over a year. There have been no changes to this service in that time.

The error occurs from both my development PC and our on-premise TFS build server. I can't figure out if this is a problem our end (with our network / firewall) or with Azure. I've tried with differing timeouts on the HTTP client, and setting values for content/request sizes in the app.config.

**None of these values had any affect.**

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

I get an **HTTP 504 (Gateway Timeout)** error when I view the request in Fiddler.

Comment: Please check if you have set up  Azure Application Gateway Web Application Firewall, if yes, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-waf-configuration to modify WAF request size limites

Comment: Also try to set "maxRequestLength" which is for ASP.NET. "maxAllowedContentLength" is for IIS. You need to set both values, the smaller one takes priority.

Comment: I'm not using an Azure Application Gateway WAF. I have tried setting values for "maxRequestLength" and "maxAllowedContentLength" but they haven't made any difference. This was all working perfectly until last week when I suddently got the error. I can't see what would have changed to produce the error.